# How to get Grafana to display these stats properly?

Tags: grafana

I'm trying to create a Stats panel in Grafana, but it's coming out like this:

[image]

i.e., it's got those 3 extra useless 'stats', CAD:CAD, EUR:EUR, USD:USD and I can't figure out how to get rid of them.

The data looks like this:

```
...
  "response": {
    "results": {
      "A": {
        "refId": "A",
        "meta": {
          "executedQueryString": "<bleep>",
          "rowCount": 3
        },
        "series": null,
        "tables": [
          {
            "columns": [
              {
                "text": "amount"
              },
              {
                "text": "currency"
              }
            ],
            "rows": [
              [
                "$74.19",
                "CAD"
              ],
              [
                "€0.94",
                "EUR"
              ],
              [
                "$28.59",
                "USD"
              ]
            ],
            "type": "table",
            "refId": "A",
            "meta": {
              "executedQueryString": "<bleep>",
              "rowCount": 3
            }
          }
        ],
        "dataframes": null
      }
    }
  }
}
```

i.e. just 3 rows in the response, exactly like I want/expect.

The config looks like:

```
{
  "datasource": "MySQL",
  "description": "",
  "fieldConfig": {
    "defaults": {
      "custom": {
        "align": null,
        "filterable": false
      },
      "unit": "none",
      "min": 0,
      "displayName": "$__cell_1",
      "color": {
        "fixedColor": "green",
        "mode": "fixed"
      },
      "thresholds": {
        "mode": "absolute",
        "steps": [
          {
            "color": "green",
            "value": null
          }
        ]
      },
      "mappings": []
    },
    "overrides": []
  },
  "gridPos": {
    "h": 8,
    "w": 11,
    "x": 11,
    "y": 35
  },
  "hideTimeOverride": true,
  "id": 23763571993,
  "interval": "1d",
  "options": {
    "reduceOptions": {
      "values": true,
      "calcs": [
        "count"
      ],
      "fields": "/.*/"
    },
    "orientation": "auto",
    "textMode": "value_and_name",
    "colorMode": "value",
    "graphMode": "area",
    "justifyMode": "auto"
  },
  "pluginVersion": "7.3.1",
  "targets": [
    {
      "format": "table",
      "group": [],
      "metricColumn": "count(*)",
      "rawQuery": true,
      "rawSql": "<bleep>",
      "refId": "A",
      "select": [
        [
          {
            "params": [
              "base_amount"
            ],
            "type": "column"
          }
        ]
      ],
      "table": "<bleep>",
      "timeColumn": "create_date_utc",
      "where": []
    }
  ],
  "timeFrom": "30d",
  "timeShift": null,
  "title": "Stripe RevShare",
  "type": "stat"
}
```

What do I have to change so it only shows those first 3 records?

I'm using Grafana v7.3.1 (6668161a88)

Comment: Try to create timeseries, so return also the time column, e. g. NOW() AS "time" and format it as timeseries.

Comment: I don't want a timeseries. That's why I'm using I'm using Stat instead of Graph. I want one Stat per currency.

Comment: Whole Grafana (stat panel included) is designated for timeseries, so I'm giving you advice how to fake it. It may fix your visualization problem. If you have table format obligation, then you should mention it in the question.

Comment: @JanGaraj Oh I see.. but where is this "timeseries" option? If I just add a time column it gets worse: https://mpen.xyz/share/2021/07/chrome_2021-07-25_14-04-47.png

Comment: Under query editor is the the select box, where you need to select timeseries format. There is a table format atm.